Usage Grazel or Airin for migrating gradle project to bazel
I have an Android project with 4 modules and gradle as build tool. Now I want to migrate it to Bazel. These plugins are useable for this purpose, but I can't find any example about it and have various issues for implementing them myself. Actually one of them must be enough for migrating, but information in their GitHub repository about usage didn't work for me.
Specially İ face problem about ksp like this :

no such target '@@com_github_google_ksp//:symbol-processing-api.jar':
target 'symbol-processing-api.jar' not declared in package '' defined
by
C:/users/user/_bazel_user/buzrtprb/external/com_github_google_ksp/BUILD.bazel
and referenced by
'@@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin/compiler:symbol-processing-api'

Does anyone have experience with migration to Bazel or use it as a build tool?
For detailed information ->
This is workspace file :
workspace(name = "ma_starter_android")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl",  "http_archive")

# Android rules
RULES_ANDROID_VERSION = "0.1.1"
RULES_ANDROID_SHA = "cd06d15dd8bb59926e4d65f9003bfc20f9da4b2519985c27e190cddc8b7a7806"

http_archive(
    name = "rules_android",
    sha256 = RULES_ANDROID_SHA,
    strip_prefix = "rules_android-%s" % RULES_ANDROID_VERSION,
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android/archive/v%s.zip" % RULES_ANDROID_VERSION],
)
android_sdk_repository(
  name = "androidsdk",
  api_level = 34,
  build_tools_version = "34.0.0"
)

rules_kotlin_version = "1.9.0"
rules_kotlin_sha = "5766f1e599acf551aa56f49dab9ab9108269b03c557496c54acaf41f98e2b8d6"
http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_kotlin",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_kotlin/releases/download/v%s/rules_kotlin-v%s.tar.gz" % (rules_kotlin_version, rules_kotlin_version)],
    sha256 = rules_kotlin_sha,
)

load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:repositories.bzl",
    "kotlin_repositories",
    "kotlinc_version",
)

kotlin_repositories(compiler_release = kotlinc_version(
    release = "1.8.21",
    sha256 = "6e43c5569ad067492d04d92c28cdf8095673699d81ce460bd7270443297e8fd7",
))

load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl",  "kt_register_toolchains")
kt_register_toolchains()


# JVM external
http_archive(
  name = "rules_jvm_external",
  strip_prefix = "rules_jvm_external-4.1",
  sha256 = "f36441aa876c4f6427bfb2d1f2d723b48e9d930b62662bf723ddfb8fc80f0140",
  url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/archive/4.1.zip"
)

load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl",  "maven_install")
load("@rules_jvm_external//:specs.bzl",  "maven")

maven_install(
  artifacts =   [
    "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.2",
    "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0",
    "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1",
    "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4",

    #   RESOLVE CONFLICTS

    "androidx.core:core:1.12.0",
    "androidx.savedstate:savedstate-ktx:1.2.0",
    "androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core-ktx:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.7.0",  
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0",
    "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0",
    "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0",
    "androidx.databinding:viewbinding:8.3.1",
    "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2",
    "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7",
    "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7",
    "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1",
    "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1",
    "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1",
    "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha06",
    "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0",
    "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0",
    "com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0",
    "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0",
    "com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0",
    "com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android",
    "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1",
    "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.12.0",
    "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0",
    "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-kotlinx-serialization:2.11.0",
    "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0",
    "io.insert-koin:koin-android:2.1.6",
    "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.1.6",
    "io.insert-koin:koin-core:2.1.6",
    "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.23",
    "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.1",
    "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.3",
  ],
  repositories =   [
    "https://maven.google.com",
    "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
  ]
version_conflict_policy = "pinned",

  fail_on_missing_checksum = False,
  resolve_timeout = 600
)


This is app modules build file :
load("@rules_android//android:rules.bzl","android_library")

android_library(
    name = "app",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.kt"]),
    custom_package = "az.pashabank.starter",
    manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["src/main/res/**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//data",
        "//domain",
        "//presentation",
        "@maven//:io_insert_koin_koin_android",
        "@maven//:com_jakewharton_timber_timber",
    ],
)

android_binary(
    name = "app_bin",
    incremental_dexing = 1,
    manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
    manifest_values = {
        "applicationId": "az.pashabank.starter",
        "minSdkVersion": "21",
        "targetSdkVersion": "34",
        "versionCode": "1",
        "versionName": "v0.0.1",
    },
    multidex = "native",
    deps = [":app"],
)

This is data modules build file which ksp related config must be set :
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:android.bzl", "kt_android_library")
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:core.bzl", "kt_ksp_plugin")
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:jvm.bzl", "kt_jvm_library")

kt_ksp_plugin(
    name = "ksp_room_plugin",
    processor_class = "androidx.room.compiler.processing.javac.JavacProcessingEnv",
    deps = [
        "@maven//:androidx_room_room_compiler",
    ],
)

kt_jvm_library(
    name = "data",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.kt"]),                                               ],
    custom_package = "az.pashabank.starter.data",
    manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["src/main/res/**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//domain",
        "@maven//:androidx_core_core_ktx",
        "@maven//:androidx_annotation_annotation",
        "@maven//:io_insert_koin_koin_core",
        "@maven//:io_insert_koin_koin_android",
        "@maven//:org_jetbrains_kotlinx_kotlinx_coroutines_core",
        "@maven//:org_jetbrains_kotlinx_kotlinx_serialization_json",
        "@maven//:com_squareup_okhttp3_okhttp",
        "@maven//:com_squareup_retrofit2_retrofit",
        "@maven//:com_squareup_retrofit2_converter_kotlinx_serialization",
        "@maven//:com_squareup_okhttp3_logging_interceptor",
        "@maven//:androidx_security_security_crypto",
        "@maven//:androidx_room_room_runtime",
        "@maven//:androidx_room_room_ktx",
        "@maven//:com_jakewharton_timber_timber",
    ],
    plugins = [":ksp_room_plugin",],

)

This is domain modules build file :
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:kotlin.bzl", "kt_jvm_library")

kt_jvm_library(
    name = "domain",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.kt"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@maven//:org_jetbrains_kotlinx_kotlinx_coroutines_core",
        "@maven//:io_insert_koin_koin_core",
    ],
)

This is presentation module build file :
load("@io_bazel_rules_kotlin//kotlin:android.bzl", "kt_android_library")


kt_android_library(
    name = "presentation",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.kt"]),
    custom_package = "az.pashabank.starter.presentation",
    manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
   resource_files = glob(["src/main/res/**"], exclude=["**/.DS_Store", "**/*/.DS_Store"]),
   visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//domain",
        "@maven//:androidx_core_core_ktx",
        "@maven//:androidx_appcompat_appcompat",
        "@maven//:androidx_fragment_fragment_ktx",
        "@maven//:androidx_activity_activity_ktx",
        "@maven//:com_google_android_material_material",
        "@maven//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_extensions",
        "@maven//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_viewmodel_ktx",
        "@maven//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_livedata_ktx",
        "@maven//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_runtime_ktx",
        "@maven//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_common_java8",
        "@maven//:androidx_constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
        "@maven//:androidx_navigation_navigation_fragment_ktx",
        "@maven//:androidx_navigation_navigation_ui_ktx",
        "@maven//:com_facebook_shimmer_shimmer",
        "@maven//:androidx_viewpager2_viewpager2",
        "@maven//:io_insert_koin_koin_android",
        "@maven//:io_insert_koin_koin_androidx_viewmodel",
        "@maven//:com_jakewharton_timber_timber",
        "@maven//:androidx_swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout",
        "@maven//:com_google_guava_guava",
        "@maven//:com_github_bumptech_glide_glide",
    ],
)


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please provide a minimal example to reproduce the issue

I edited and added config files in question's summary . Please check
